# gnuplot interpret variable as string

Tags: string, gnuplot

I have a variable:
`ylab="Temperature \260C"`
and I want to set that as the ylabel, but:
`set ylabel ylab`
or
`set ylabel sprintf("%s",ylab)`
results in \260 being printed, rather than it being interpreted as a degree symbol.

How can I get gnuplot to interpret the variable as a string?

Answer (score 0):

simply use

`set ylabel "Temperature °C"`

or

`set ylabel "Temperature ".GPVAL_DEGREE_SIGN."C"`

Comment: Yes, I realise that, but in my case I have the label in a variable.

Comment: Version 5.2 patchlevel 6    last modified 2019-01-01

Comment: If I define `ylab="Temperature \260C"` and `set ylabel ylab`, I get the desired result on gnuplot 5.2.6 on Win7. What is your operating system?

Comment: Raspbian Buster (Linux) on a Raspberry Pi

Comment: HaHaa, that works for me as well.  So, my problem is the way I'm setting up the string.  I'm sending it in to gnuplot on the command line:  `gnuplot -e "ylab='$ylab'" SH.gp`